# Instale KB 2919355 antes de instalar Visual ? - error al intentar instalar visual studio 2015

Tags: c#

Alguien que use profesional c# - visual studio 2015, tengo el siguiente problema:

intento instalar el visual studio version 2015 y me pide que instale una actualizaciones (nota: ya las instale) y me sigue pidiendo lo mismo y ya la reinicie la PC y nada de nada , sigue este mensaje :/

Investigue aqui :

[foro de c#](http://investigue%20Aqui%20y%20tampoco%20y%20realize%20lo%20que%20dice%20y%20aun%20sigue%20con%20el%20error%20::https://www.visualstudio.com/es/vs/support/vs2015/received-error-version-visual-studio-requires-april-2014-update-windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-known-kb-2919355/)

[foro de c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dce77ee9-8fcc-4a21-8a47-b45b9c5163d8/visual-community-2015-setup-blocked-installation-loop?forum=vssetup)

Cual podria ser mi error ?

NOTA : soy nuevo con c# y mas con visual studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta ejecutar este comando (la ruta puede variar) `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>Ldr64.exe set64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te contesto por aquí ya que no me deja añadir comentarios.
Yo tuve un problema similar, lo más probable es que los registros de tu PC no estén correctos, Microsoft ofrece una herramienta para ayudar a corregirlos, a mi personalmente no me ha funcionado, si el problema persiste lo mejor que puedes hacer es formatear o restablecer pc si eliges esta última opción tienes que marcar que no guarde programas antiguos, ya que si los guardas tendras el mismo problema.

Comment: ¿Cual es la herramienta?

Comment: Ahora mismo no la tengo a mano, pero con buscar para reparar los registros de Visual Studio debería salirte